# Comparing different ways of specifying the same response variable

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, regression-coefficients

I have a question about different ways of specifying a response variable in a model and what effect this could have on my results.

In my example, I wanted to model the number of times a bird visits a nest to feed its young during a set period of time. So the data would be a set of counts, let's call it `Number of Visits`. Now one thing that might affect how many visits an adult makes is the size of the brood (`Brood Size`). I have seen two ways of modeling this in the literature:

1. Have Number of Visits as the response variable and include Brood Size as an explanatory variable.
2. Have Number of Visits/ Brood Size as the response variable and include other explanatory variables as appropriate.

How would these approaches differ and is either superior to the other, would each approach give a different answer?

I can see that using each approach you might be modeling subtly different things. In option `1)` you seem to be modeling the overall number of visits while controlling for brood size, whereas in option `2)` you seem to be measuring the per capita number of visits.

Answer (score 2):

Unless it is common practice, I would avoid working with ratios as a response.  You already have a response rate, visits/per unit of time.    This is a typical count regression response-usually but not always fit with Poisson regression.  I would build a model with brood size and the other explanatory variables.